# Spring Boot app with Redis insert data on startup

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, redis, spring-data

I am working on a Spring Boot app that uses Redis as the primary data store. Is there a way to insert data into the Redis db on application startup the way we do it for MongoDB using a Mongeez script?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

many years ago, I used ApplicationRunner to do something

Comment: You mean to say extending from ApplicationRunner and then overriding the run() method? Yeah I knew about that. I was hoping for a mongeez-like solution.